# Python-Pandas-How to add an empty row before the header in CSV file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, null

I have dataframe where i exported the output to a csv file. Now in the csv file i require an empty row before the header .so that final output csv file will have empty row first followed by header and data.

Output CSV file:

```
ID CLASS SCHOOL
1   4    ABC
2   5    CDE
```

Expected output CSV file:

```
an empty row first
ID CLASS SCHOOL
1   4    ABC
2   5    CDE
```

Tried different codes, but none of them works.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df1.values, index+1, values=[" "] * len(df1.columns), axis=0),columns = df1.columns)

writer =csv.writer('CorePreviousWorkexp.csv')
df1.to_csv(writer, sheet_name='Concentrado',startrow=1, startcol= 1, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `DataFrame.to_csv()` without specifying the file (it prints to standard output) and redirect this output to file:

```py
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    print(file=f_out)    # print empty line
    print(df.to_csv(index=False), end='', file=f_out)
```

This creates `data.csv` with contents:

```
ID,CLASS,SCHOOL
1,4,ABC
2,5,CDE
```

Comment: very nice trick @Andrej love it ;)

Comment: Thanks  @Andrej .However doing this way created an  empty row before header but also created an extra line between each row of the output file.

Comment: @technical Can you try `with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='',  encoding='utf-8') as f_out:` ?